# Is it possible to buffer an error execution in Tricentis Tosca?

Tags: google-chrome, error-handling, buffer, tosca

I'd like to know if I can buffer an execution error in Tricentis Tosca.
I am creating automated tests on Google Chrome and I would like to buffer the errors that Tosca gives me when there is something wrong (that log would be used in the recovery/cleanup scenario).
[image: example of the error i'd like to buffer]

Comment: not clear what you want to buffer. The loginfo? How do you intend to use it?

Comment: i need the loginfo (just the part that throws the error) so i can log into my server

Comment: it's still not clear. You need the text in that cell? Or you need the test step which causes that error? You want to use it how?

Comment: I need the text in that cell, but i think it's not possible

Comment: i know this is an old thread but has anyone figured this out?

Comment: i believe this feature was requested to Tricentis but they haven't made it yet and I don't know if they are ever going to